# Reduce communication volume of graph partition in METIS

Tags: graph, partitioning, metis

I have been using METIS to partition a graph. As of now, I am not using any special options, so I presume METIS is partitioning the graph while minimizing the edge cut.

Thing is, the graphs I am working on has few vertices that have a lot of neighbors. I guess that means I will have to pass the option to reduce the communication volume as opposed to edge cut.

How do I do this? I do not understand what is the point of the vsize parameter in section 5.8 page 26. Do I need to mess with ncon or vwgt, or objval? Do I just do options[METIS_OPTION_OBJTYPE] = METIS_OBJTYPE_VOL and pass it to the function?

Also, for a graph that may not have the number of vertices as power of 2, which variant of the function should I use? k-way(most probably) or bisection?

I would have asked these questions on the METIS forums but unfortunately it has been a while since I registered for it without any reply from their website so I am asking here.

Answer (score 0):

'vsize' is for specifying the communication volume associated with a vertex. For most applications, you will not need to specify this as it is assumed to be one. If you do not have balance constraints, you can ignore ncon and vwgt. The objval variable simply lets you know what the value of the objective is for the generated partition (total weight of cut edges or total communication volume).

You will want to use k-way partition for larger numbers of partitions as it will tend to be faster, and may produces results of higher quality. Both will handle non-power of two numbers of partitions. The number of vertices does not matter.